# Global assumption non zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, variable-definitions, sets

I would like to define globally an assumption stating that I have a nonzero real vector $v$.

For now, I put :

`$Assumptions = Element[v,Vectors[{100},Reals]]`

but $v$ can be zero.

Is there a ways to write automatically the fact that the components of $v$ are not identically equal to zero ?

Comment: What about `PositiveReals`?

Comment: Can some components be zero if some other components are non-zero?

Comment: @Syed my components can be negative and I don't know how to combine `PositiveReals` with `NegativeReals`  

@mszynisz Yes, some components can be zero.